# fingerdetection in MIT's mit-ros-pkg didn't run well

Tags: ros, kinect, hand-interaction, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I ran the finger_detection demo in MIT's mit-ros-pkg. It had no compiling error and ran OK and the prime sense viewer successfully tracked person's skeleton.

But the finger data didn't show in Rviz. The messages from */finger_norms* topic didn't show the yellowing WARNING and are said to be received but the line segment which should have represent the finger direction didn't show on screen.

I rostopic echo the /finger_norms and get the following result.

What does it mean?

```
> ~$rostopic echo /finger_norms header:   
> seq: 80   stamp: 
>     secs: 1324897142
>     nsecs: 445125858   frame_id: /openni_rgb_optical_frame polygons: []
> chan: []
> --- header:    seq: 81   stamp: 
>     secs: 1324897231
>     nsecs: 344789294   frame_id: /openni_rgb_optical_frame polygons: []
> chan: []
> --- ^C
```

I am using ROS electric and UBUNTU 10.10.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12457/fingerdetection-in-mit%27s-mit-ros-pkg-didn%27t-run-well/) by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2011-12-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a probably useful and correct answer for my own question here.([Finger detection doesn't work well.](http://answers.ros.org/question/12581/finger-detection-doesnt-work-well))

In my case I edited the `tol` parameter, and it runs better now.

---

Originally posted by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) with karma: 130 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0